# Is my new portable harddrive compatible with Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, 14.10, compatibility

I have a question regarding a portable harddrive. I just got it as a present but I didnt open it, because on the back it says system requirements are Windows or Mac. However on the webpage I found that it is also compatible with Linux Kernel 2.6 or higher, but what does that mean? Can I use it with Ubuntu 14.10?

The name of the harddrive is Verbatim Store'n'Go Superspeed Portable Hard Drive 1 TB and it is USB 3.0 but it says it is 100% compatible with USB 2.0 (My laptop has 2.0)

I don't really know much about these things and my guess is that the shop where it is bought also wouldn't know it, so I hope somebody can help :)

Answer (score 1):

USB 3.0 disks have been compatible with Linux for quite some time now (some years, at least). Ubuntu 14.10 is using [Linux kernel version 3.16](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/linux-generic), which is higher than 2.6.

You can confirm this by opening a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and running:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-43-generic
```

(I'm on 14.04, which is currently on the 3.13 kernel version.)